# JQuery PNG Fix Plugin - Doesn't work so well?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have just switched over from the old png transparency fix using a htc file and I have started using a JQuery plugin called [JQueryPngFix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/). I have to migrate because I have started using JQuery and its conflicing with the htc file.

The thing is, it works but it seems to have over-layed the PNG (sends it to front rather than as a background!) on the whole div to the extent that I can not click on the content underneath, which is what makes me think the PNG has expanded or something, even though it looks exactly the way I want it to. I can't exactly debug this on IE6, since they have nothing like firebug, so was wondering if anyone can take a shot in the dark on what might be the problem.

```
#box{
background-image:url(../images/checkout_fuzzy.png);
background-position:inherit;
margin:0 auto;
width:800px;
height:auto;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `background-position: inherit`?

Comment: I've fired up the plugin and tried to replicate the problem with your css, but it all looks fine.  Can we see your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My png fixing solution of choice is [iFixPng](http://jquery.khurshid.com/ifixpng.php), and I've never had your particular problem when using it. You may also want to look at the [improved version](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iFixPng2), though I had issues with it when it first came out and haven't tried again.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your bg image in a div by itself, so nothing else is affected. Set the position to relative, and then set a negative z-index.

If that doesn't work, can you provide a page where we can take a look at it?